# Installing Xen 4.0.1 from Source on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu, installation, xen, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to install Xen 4.0.1 from Source on Ubuntu 10.10 Server Edition. 
I started with a clean machine and followed the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen.

So I installed the packages mentioned there with: 
`sudo apt-get install gettext bin86 bcc libc6-dev-i386 iasl texinfo git`

When making the source with `make world` I get this error:

```
+ git clone -o xen -n git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/homer/xen/linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 1855434, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (291939/291939), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (1855434/1855434), 368.49 MiB | 11.00 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 1855434 (delta 1553214), reused 1847760 (delta 1546656)
Resolving deltas: 100% (1553214/1553214), done.
+ cd linux-2.6-pvops.git.tmp
+ git checkout -b xen/stable-2.6.32.x xen/xen/stable-2.6.32.x
fatal: git checkout: branch xen/stable-2.6.32.x already exists
make[3]: *** [linux-2.6-pvops.git/.valid-src] Error 128
```

Does anybody have an idea what i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit the following file: ./buildconfigs/src.git-clone (under xen folder)

edit the following line (line 29 in my config)

```
(cd $(LINUX_SRCDIR).tmp; git checkout -b $(XEN_LINUX_GIT_LOCALBRANCH) $(XEN_LINUX_GITREV) ); \
```

to look like

```
(cd $(LINUX_SRCDIR).tmp; git checkout ); \
```